# Change textwriter to write to console

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this existing function that I would like to convert so it will print the logMessage out to the console.  Originally this was used as a cmd line app that i have converted to a windows form application in C#.    How do i change the output stream so it would write to a file or the console?

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Prints a log message to stderr.
    /// </summary>

public static void logMessage(String format, params Object[] args)
    { //Change output stream if desired
        TextWriter logStream = Console.Error;
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        logStream.WriteLine(logTime() + " " + format, args);
    }
```

Comment: it does actually write into console

Answer (score 0):

To write to a file, you can replace `Console.Error` with a `StreamWriter` object.  You might need to add some locking around this method though, I'm not sure how this would handle concurrent messages from multiple threads writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now what you mean by Console... you mean some TextBox? If yes then you can do something like this:

```
public class TextBoxWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextBox _textBox = null;

    public TextBoxWriter(TextBox textBox)
    {
        _textBox = textBox;
    }

    private void AppendText(string message) 
    {
        _textBox.AppendText(message);
        _textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        base.Write(message);
        if (_textBox.InvokeRequired) 
            _textBox.Invoke(new Action<string>((msg) => AppendText(msg)), message);
        else 
            AppendText(message);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

and then

```
TextWriter logStream = new TextBoxWriter(yourTextBox);
```

If you would like to write into file then probably something like Joe suggested but remember to synchronize that part unless you're sure you'll be accessing it by only one thread.

Comment: You'll want to override `Write`, not `WriteLine`.  `WriteLine` calls `Write` (and `Write` is the only one that's virtual).  As long as `Write` is overridden, all the rest will work correctly.  You'll also probably want to invoke to the UI thread in the `Write` implementation, rather than forcing the caller to do that before doing any writing ever.

Comment: WriteLine is `virtual` as well -> http://v.gd/pbscKr. Not sure if it's good idea to override Write(char) and append to text box char by char. Yes, probably it should be invoked on UI thread.

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line

```
logStream.WriteLine(logTime() + " " + format, args);
```

With this line

```
Console.WriteLine(logTime() + " " + format, args);
```

I didn't test it but it should work!

Comment: `logStream` is a stream fetched from the console, so this will act no differently than the OP's code.  The issue is that since he now has a winform app there is no longer any console to write to.

Comment: Oops, I missed that. But then, his question doesn't make sense since it's already writing to the console...

Comment: As I said before, the OP said that he has changed his program from a console app to a winform app, so he no longer *has* a console to write to.

Comment: Every winform app in .NET still has a console. In fact, I use it a lot for debugging. I read the part where he is talking about going from command file to WinForm but he sais this: "How do i change the output stream so it would write to a file or the console". The question needs to be edited because the OP ask to write to the console when he already write to the console. That's the reason I gave this answer.

Comment: No, a winform app does *not* have a console.  You can access the VS console when debugging the program in visual studio, but that's entirely different from a windows console.

Comment: I know, but he is using visual studio 2010 and maybe I'm talking for myself but when I talk about the console, this is the console I will be looking at. Anyway, I know my answer is not good but the question is unclear too :)

Comment: The VS console is just a debugging tool, not a part of the deployed program.  Perhaps you should create a console application to see what the `Console` class is actually manipulating.